# Using a variable in Fortran's SYSTEM subroutine

Tags: fortran, system-calls

How do I use a variable in the command executed in a `system` subroutine call? For example, if I want to create multiple directories like `test_1_1`, `test_1_2`, and so on till `test_3_3` then what should my code be?

I am trying the following code but can't seem to figure out what to write in #### part.

```
integer  :: i,j

do i = 1,3
   do j = 1,3 
      CALL system('mkdir folder ####') 
   enddo
enddo
```

Answer (score 6):

```
character (len=8) :: test_name

do i=1, 3
   do j=1, 3
      write (test_name, '( "test_", I1, "_", I1 )' ) i, j
      call system ( "mkdir " // test_name )
   end do
end do
```

The format in my example will work as long as the numbers are single digits.  If you want larger values you could use `I2.2` (for up to two digits, with leading zero, if single digits), or `I0`, for whatever number of digits are needed.

Comment: thanks for your reply. However, i get the following message on compilation      error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-FILE when expecting one of: <LABEL> <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; BLOCK BLOCKDATA PROGRAM MODULE TYPE INTEGER REAL ...
enddo
-----^
compilation aborted for test.f90 (code 1)